# visual studio 2012 couldn't update stored procedures in database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Just like I described in the title, I couldn't update my stored procedures in VS 2012.
Every time I tried to update and it gave me a result show that:

Highlights:
None

User actions:
None

Supporting actions:
None

Just Don't understand why, it suddenly happened.
Thanks very much :D

Comment: Can you add more details? Like, what are the steps you are taking when trying to update your stored procedure?

Comment: With update you mean deploying your project to SQL Server?